# How to exclude wordpress working directory from the URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Folks,

I have a wordpress website. URLs are something like this, http://www.mywp.com/wordpress/post/1  as I have a folder name called wordpress which is my wordpress installation folder. `public_html/wordpress`

I have done all the developments  in that directory, hence my all post link contains the word 'wordpress' in its URLs.

So the problem is I want to get rid of from "wordpress" word and would like to  see the URL like http://www.mywp.com ,http://www.mywp.com/post/1 etc.

Any help?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I have to put some lines into your .htcaccess file:

In public_html/wordpress/ create a .htaccess file if already doesnt exists:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+wordpress([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

And also in your public_html/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule !^/?wordpress wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thnaks, But did not work If I run http://example.org/wordpress/mycontent/ things work. But if I hit http://example.org/mycontent/ I am getting The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I can see urls are get rid of from wordpress word. But still I am getting Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that it would be working,because the directory structure is `/public_html/wordpress/` so when you try to get css js folders using WordPress function they will give you directory path.

The only thing you have to do is get all the files move on public_html.
There is no option other than that.